# Remove characters after three consecutive capital letters

Tags: python

I am trying to remove all characters after 3 consecutive capital letters so for example:
Crowd_Cheer_Large_Football_Game_Applause_OCP-0098-14.wav

Explosion_Artillery_DET-0020-256_Stereo.wav

Should become :

Crowd_Cheer_Large_Football_Game_Applause_OCP

Explosion_Artillery_DET

In Python I have tried that:

```
import re
import string

text1 = 'Crowd_Cheer_Large_Football_Game_Applause_OCP-0098-14.wav'
text2 = 'Explosion_Artillery_DET-0020-256_Stereo.wav'
text1 = re.sub((?<='[A-Z]{3}'), '', text1)
text2 = re.sub((?<='[A-Z]{3}'), '', text2)
print (text1)
print (text2)
```

But apparently I can't use (?<= ... ) like that so I don't know how to do !

Thanks !

Comment: (1) The regular expression must be given as properly quoted string (literal). (2) After looking behind the regex must also specify what should follow, in this case anything: `.*`

Comment: The entire regular expression is a string: `re.sub('(?<=[A-Z]{3})')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub()` this way:

```
text1 = re.sub(r'([A-Z]{3}).*', '\\1', text1)
text2 = re.sub(r'([A-Z]{3}).*', '\\1', text2)
```

We are matching substring from and including 3 uppercase alphabets and replace them with the same 3 uppercase alphabets.

Comment: Please accept the helpful answer by pressing tick on left of answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this out. Hope this helps

```py
import re

text1 = 'Crowd_Cheer_Large_Football_Game_Applause_OCP-0098-14.wav'
text2 = 'Explosion_Artillery_DET-0020-256_Stereo.wav'

x = re.search('([A-Z]){3}',text1)
y = re.search('([A-Z]){3}',text2)

index = x.start() + 3
print(text1[:index:])

index = y.start() + 3
print(text2[:index:])
```